# removing Hebrew "niqqud" using r

Tags: regex, r, text, unicode, hebrew

Have been struggling to remove [niqqud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud) ( diacritical signs used to represent vowels or distinguish between alternative pronunciations of letters of the Hebrew alphabet).
I have for instance this variable:
sample1 <- "הֻסְמַק"

And i cannot find effective way to remove the signs below the letters.

tried stringer, with `str_replace_all(sample1, "[^[:alnum:]]", "")`
tried `gsub('[:punct:]','',sample1)`

no success... :-(
any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [my gsub example](http://ideone.com/1IxAeA), does it work for you?

Comment: @stribizhev - thank you very much! it worked like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\p{M}` Unicode category to match diacritics with Perl-like regex, and `gsub` all of them in one go like this:

```
sample1 <- "הֻסְמַק"
gsub("\\p{M}", "", sample1, perl=T)
```

Result: `[1] "הסמק"`

See [demo](http://ideone.com/1IxAeA)

> `\p{M}` or `\p{Mark}`: a character intended to be combined with another character (e.g. accents, umlauts, enclosing boxes, etc.).

See more at [Regular-Expressions.info, *"Unicode Categories"*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category).