# Removing Hebrew vowels / niqqud using php

Tags: php

I found this solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716995/remove-niqqud-from-string-in-javascript)
but its in javascript, I try to do it with PHP and I got a warning.

Here is my code:

```
$dynamicstring = 'שָׁמַיִם';
$newstring2 = preg_replace('[\u0591-\u05C7]', '', $dynamicstring);
```

The warning I have got:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 1 in
```

What is it mean? so if it not support what can I use?

**Edit:**
I was able to do this by the following code:

```
preg_replace('/[^\w$\x-\x]+/u', '', $dynamicstring);
```

*But this code remove spaces between words in the string, how to fix that?*

**Second Edit:**
the solution is to do this:

```
preg_replace('/[^\w$\x-s-\x]+/u', '', $dynamicstring);
```

I added `-s-` between the `\x`s

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458654/regular-expressions-for-a-range-of-unicode-points-php?

Comment: @user3783243 I try the samples and here what I do: ``$newstring2 = preg_replace('/[^\w$\x{0591}-\x{05C7}]+/u', '', $dynamicstring);``, nothing happens

Comment: What should happen, what is a hebrew vowel? The `\w` probably contradicts your other statements, I get no errors though and have no knowledge of hebrew so you really nned to add more to the question. https://3v4l.org/oLlVD

Comment: @user3783243 please see edit, the code I wrote work fine and remove the hebrew vowels but it remove spaces between words in the string too, how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

These are non-spacing marks, so (assuming the string is in UTF-8) they can be stripped using the [Unicode character property](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) syntax:

```
<?php

$dynamicstring = 'שָׁמַיִם';
$newstring2 = preg_replace('/\p{Mn}/u', '', $dynamicstring);
var_dump($newstring2); // results in string(8) "שמים"
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/KpsZM3

Comment: Thanks but I solved the problem with another regex - I have a question, what is it mean ``{Mn}``?

Comment: '**M**ark, **n**on-spacing'. There's a table with all property designators on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) (also linked in the answer body).